# Neo4j Javascript application with sigma.js and bolt

Tags: javascript, neo4j, server, sigma.js, bolt

I have helped to create a web app that uses sigma.js to display a graphical output, on top of a neo4j database.

I am trying to use the neo4j-driver with this to enable me to set this web app up on a remote server, with its own version of neo4j community edition constantly running.

The issue at the moment is that whenever you run the web app through remote connection to the server, it only links to neo4j if you are running the on your local machine.

I was told to download the above driver and use bolt protocol to fix this however I cannot get this to work.

I am not the most experience coder however I have tried using require('neo4j-driver') to no avail and I have also tried just linking it to 'bolt://localhost:7867.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
var url_ = 'bolt://localhost:7687' 
var pword = 'neo4j2' 
sigma.neo4j.getLabels(
        { url: url_, user: 'neo4j', password: pword },
        function (labels) {
            console.log(labels)
            NodeLabels = labels;
            console.log("NodeLabels: " + NodeLabels);
        }
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you enabled remote connections to the server:
https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-enable-remote-https-access-with-neo4j-30x/

Comment: forgot to mention instead of http connector, you have to change bolt config similarly: dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have not enabled remote connections on the Neo4j server.
Depending upon what connector you want to change, you will have to uncomment, change that configuration.
Refer to official neo4j connector config: [Connector Config](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/)

Example config change:

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, sorry for my lateness in replying back to you. I have done the changes you recommend however I get the following error in the browser console: 'Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.'

Comment: full error: sigma.parsers.cypher.js:68 Failed to load bolt://0.0.0.0:7687/db/data/transaction/commit: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: I have updated my question above with some of the code, I have tried it with port 7687 and 7867.

Comment: @JamesTimmins can you try changing the url to http://localhost:7474
Also, I thought you were running neo4j on another machine. But any case, instead of bolt try using http and check if that works

Comment: Hi Himanshu, we have tried that. The issue is we are accessing our app via internet browser as its on a remote server. If you use http it then looks for server on your local machine and not the one running on the remote server that it is running on.

Comment: shouldn't be the case. Why will it look for that on the local machine when you have provided the ip of the remote machine while making the rest calls.

Comment: Yes, when you use the ip it doesn't work full stop. When you use local host it looks on your local machine. I know this because it works when I have a local instance of neo4j running and it doesn't work when I don't.

Comment: Sorry i haven't been able to help. did you change this line too in config:

dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

Comment: No worries, thank you for trying. And yes I did change that line.